# Is the distance of an element $a$ from a subspace $M$ always $||a-P_M a||$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The distance of an element $a$ from a subspace $M$ is $||a-P_Ma||$? ($P_Ma$ is the orthogonal projection of $a$ on $M$). During the course of studying about Hilbert Spaces and The Operators Theory, I have noticed that it was always direct in the course notes that the distance between some point $a$ from a subspace $M$, generally being the infimum of $||a-y||$ over all $y\in M$, is $||a-P_Ma||$. While it does make sense, is there a simple way of showing why it automatically holds? Maybe it was explained in the notes, but as for a specific case and without making much of an admissible statement, and I have no idea how it is generalized. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_M$ must be the *orthogonal* projection. That means that $a-P_Ma$ is othogonal to $M$ and hence for any $x\in M$, we have $\|a-x\|^2=\|a-P_Ma\|^2+\|P_Ma-x\|^2\ge \|a-P_Ma\|^2$ (with equality iff $x=P_Ma$).

Comment: I forgot the orthogonality property. That actually makes great sense. Thank you.